# ASP.NET ActionLink to a created View doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The first 3 lines are standard on the Index page. I made a new View page with Razor called "Rijbewijs"

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Rijbewijs", "Rijbewijs", new { id=item.ID })
```

The first 3 links are working, what did I do wrong with the new one?

The code below is what I have in my View Rijbewijs:

```
@model Autorijschool3.Models.Instructeur

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rijbewijs";
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you add a controller?

Comment: Do you have an action method named Rijbewijs that returns that view? `public ActionResult Rijbewijs(int id)`

Comment: You should probably go through some tutorials or on-line training to understand how MVC works. There are several options available at http://www.asp.net/mvc. Bottom line, in MVC the link doesn't point to a view, it points to an action (i.e. method) on a controller.